# What does "drafty" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is:

> DAVID: I wish I had children.
>   FANNY: How could you? All the women you like are too **drafty**, if you know what I mean. None of them could have children. Which, as God in his wisdom, would have it.

I couldn't find in the Internet any definition of "drafty" except "cold and uncomfortable because of currents of cool air".  Now, I understand there may be some sort of irony, but the comparing a draft and women who can't have children doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Could you give us the source? From the spelling, I'm guessing that it's American. It **may** mean *flat-chested*.

Comment: It's from movie of "Watch on the Rhine" (1943). It's an American movie and the character is American.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is retained from the play by Lillian Hellman, which her lover Dashiell Hammett followed very closely in writing the screenplay. Earlier in the play, Sara and her mother discuss David's girlfriends before David arrives:

> SARA.   Why hasn’t he married?
>   FANNY.    Really, I don’t know. I don’t think he likes his own taste. Which is very discriminating of him. He’s had a lot of girls, of course, one more ignorant and silly than the other —

*Drafty* (*draughty* in Hellman's original) is Fanny's ironically euphemistic expression for the ignorance and silliness of the women David likes. They're not physically incapable of childbearing, just too self-absorbed and empty-headed—today we say "air-headed"—to endure the trouble of bearing children.

Comment: I agree this is the more likely explanation than the "past birthing age" the other answer suggests.  My impression is that it's similar to the colloquialism "flighty".

Comment: @Andrew Agreed - knowing the context helps, and I'll admit to only skimming through the script (which, in the version I've found, didn't even properly attribute the lines). It still doesn't seem to be an actual English idiom, but this interpretation makes much more sense.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski It's not idiomatic: Fanny marks it as a nonce-usage with *if you know what I mean*. ... Those "scripts" you find on the internet are I believe ripped from subtitle tracks.

Comment: It might be anachronistic for the original time period, but "wind between your ears" is a concept that has some modern currency. The implication is that there's nothing (i.e. no brain) to stop wind from going in one ear and out the other. I could see "drafty" being used similarly, implying that their head is empty (and unkept) enough to experience drafts.

Comment: @R.M. Fersher. Their heads are open to the wind, but there's nothing there to be stirred up but dust.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I can spend an hour talking to my Australian neighbor and learn a dozen idioms I'd never heard before (e.g. ["daggy"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=daggy)).  "Drafty" might have been something the author knew would be used by people from that time and place, or perhaps something she just made up that seems to fit.

Comment: A famous example of this is Mario Puzo's "The Godfather".  The author never met an Italian gangster but imagined how they would speak -- apparently so well that real mobsters started to imitate how the characters talk in the film version.

Comment: @Andrew it is a contemporary play and movie, though, taking place in 1940s. Curiously, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drafty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrafty%3B%2Cc0) shows a large spike of the word's usage right around 1943 - I wonder if that's related, or if it's just the similarity to the word "draft" (which I imagine would be used fairly often during the wartime).

Comment: @R.M. oh, haven't thought of the "nothing between the ears" implied meaning. A pretty clever euphemism, if that's the case.